# Integrating $\int_0^\pi e^{\cos t} dt$.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis, definite-integrals

I’d like help with computing the following integral:

> $$\int_{0}^{\pi} e^{\cos t}\,dt$$

(This is a problem in complex analysis [supposedly].)

Comment: I don't see any way of doing this with pencil and paper. Could you just put this into a calculator?

Comment: these are related questions (if not generalization of yours): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/744474/int-e-cosx-cosnx-dx-using-the-residue-theorem and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/740514/residue-theorem-with-exponential-and-trig-functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(the complex analysis way)

$\cos t$ is even hence $$\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{\cos t} dt = 2 \int_0^{\pi} e^{\cos t} dt$$

then apply the (complex) change of variable $z = e^{it}, dz = i e^{it} dt$, $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{\cos t} dt = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{\frac{e^{it}+e^{-it}}{2}} (-i e^{-it}) i e^{it} dt = -i\int_{\gamma} e^{\frac{z+z^{-1}}{2}} z^{-1} dz$$

with $\gamma$ the unit circle traversed counter-clockwise.

the only one singularity inside the contour is at $z=0$, where $$e^{\frac{z+z^{-1}}{2}} z^{-1} = z^{-1}\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^k}{2^k k!}\right)\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^{-k}}{2^k k!}\right) = z^{-1}\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty z^n \sum_{k=\max(0,n)}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k k!}\frac{1}{2^{k-n} (k-n)!} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n z^n$$

with $$c_{-1} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{2k} (k!)^2}= Res\left(e^{\frac{z+z^{-1}}{2}} z^{-1},0\right)$$

hence

$$\int_{\gamma} e^{\frac{z+z^{-1}}{2}} z^{-1} dz = 2 i \pi c_{-1}$$

$$\int_0^{\pi} e^{\cos t} dt = \frac{-i}{2} \int_{\gamma} e^{\frac{z+z^{-1}}{2}} z^{-1} dz = \pi \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{2k} (k!)^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: expand the exponential in a power series, and express the cosine in terms of exponential functions.  The answer turns out to involve a modified [Bessel function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I.CE.B1_.2C_K.CE.B1).  In fact, one of the formulas on that page contains the answer.

Comment: This was an exam question. The answer is presumably not supposed to be in terms of special functions (other than maybe sinusoidal functions).

Comment: can you check if the result agrees with mine ?

Comment: Yes, it does.  $$\pi\sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{1}{2^{2k} (k!)^2} = \pi I_0(1)$$

Comment: Presumably, if you have not studied modified Bessel functions, the intended answer on the exam was the series representation.  You won't get a "closed form"  answer that doesn't involve special functions.